# nginx redirect - urls with/without parameters

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have included the following lines in my `nginx_config` file:

```
location = /xalia/ps/1/ {
  return 301 /xalia;
}
location = /xalia/ps/1/?type=1 {
  return 301 /xalia/monterna;
}
```

Redirection works OK, but `/xalia/ps/1/?type=1` redirects to `/xalia` instead of to `/xalia/monterna`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Change the order. The first match will win.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider changing the order has the same result

Comment: nginx's `location` strips query before matching. You have to use `if`

Comment: @AlexeyTen please post an answer with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
location = /xalia/ps/1/ {
    # Rewrite
    if ($args ~* "type=1") {
        rewrite .* /xalia/moderna permanent;
    }
    rewrite .* /xalia permanent;
}
```